# switch statement for an std::pair?

Tags: c++11, switch-statement, pattern-matching

I want to switch over possible values of two integers, or in another case two bools. For the sake of discussion, suppose I've done

```
auto mypair = std::make_pair(foo, bar);
```

How can I achieve the equivalent of

```
switch(mypair) {
case make_pair(true, false): cout << "true and false"; break;
case make_pair(false, true)  cout << "false and true"; break;
case default: cout << "something else";
}
```

with C++11? (C++14/17 also relevant if that helps)?

Comment: I guess [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch) would help. See in particular what's expected as a *condition* and how it is defined the *constant_expression* of the *case* statement before to proceed. What do you expect exactly from your snippet?

Answer (score 7):

You can only switch on an integral type, but if you can devise a function to map your pair (or any complex type) to an integral type, you can declare it as `constexpr` (C++11) to indicate it can be resolved at compile time. Then it is acceptable as a case expression.

Simple example:

```
enum Action { peel, eat, juice };
enum Fruit { apple, orange, banana };

constexpr unsigned int switch_pair(Action a, Fruit f) {
   return (a << 16) + f;
}
```

Then define the switch like this:

```
switch(switch_pair(mypair.first,mypair.second))
{
   case switch_pair(peel,apple):  std::cout << "Peeling an apple" << std::endl; break;
   case switch_pair(eat,apple):   std::cout << "Eating an apple" << std::endl; break;
   case switch_pair(juice,apple): std::cout << "Juicing an apple" << std::endl; break;
   default:
      throw std::runtime_error("We only have apples!");
}
```

Comment: Wow - this is the first time I have see a constexpr use case that is a coding win for my codebase.  Love it! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

C++'s switch statement doesn't have the pattern matching power of many other languages. You'll need to take a slightly different approach.

Here's a possibility I threw together:

```
pair_switch(my_pair,
    std::make_tuple(true, false, []{ std::cout << "true and false"; }),
    std::make_tuple(false, true, []{ std::cout << "false and true"; }));
```

You supply a `std::pair<bool,bool>` and a set of cases as `std::tuples`, where the first two elements match the pair you pass in and the third element is a function to call for that case.

The implementation has a few template tricks, but should be pretty usable:

```
template <typename... Ts>
void pair_switch(std::pair<bool,bool> pair, Ts&&... ts) {
    //A table for the cases
    std::array<std::function<void()>, 4> table {};

    //Fill in the cases
    (void)std::initializer_list<int> {
        (table[std::get<0>(ts)*2 + std::get<1>(ts)] = std::get<2>(ts), 0)...
    };

    //Get the function to call out of the table
    auto& func = table[pair.first*2 + pair.second];

    //If there is a function there, call it
    if (func) {
        func();   
    //Otherwise, throw an exception
    } else {
        throw std::runtime_error("No such case");   
    }
}
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/131360136113800b)

Comment: OK, you deserve a +1 in any case, at least for the way you used the `initializer_list` to fill in the array the cases. Chapeau. Does that statement simply unroll the parameter pack into the array (thus discarding the list makes sense) or there is another purpose I can't see? Love the `, 0` part, really, never thought something like that to unroll the pack, really clever!!

Comment: It uses the fact that you can unpack parameter packs in the context of `initializer_list`s, then just fills the array as a side effect and discards the `initializer_list`. This uglyness will be fixed when fold-expressions are in the language.

Comment: OK, it works as I got it, nice. Really interesting and good an idea, indeed. Fold-expressions means 202y, am I wrong?

Comment: @skypjack Hopefully 1z/17